# How can I find Average of a document item in a collection in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, average

```
   const scoreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    rollno:{
        type:Number,
        unique: true
    },
    first_round:{
        type:Number,
        validate(value){
            if(value > 10){
                throw new Error('Maximum marks is 10')
            }
        }
    },
    second_round:{
        type:Number,
        validate(value){
            if(value > 10){
                throw new Error('Maximum marks is 10')
            }
        }
    },
    third_round:{
        type:Number,
        validate(value){
            if(value > 10){
                throw new Error('Maximum marks is 10')
            }
        }
    },
    total:{
        type:Number,
        }
});
```

I need to find averages of `first_round`, `second_round` etc for all the records combined. How can I do that? I cannot figure out how we can find averages in mongoose. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share the desired output format?

Comment: I want to find average of each rounds separately. Not just for a specific roll no but for all the records, basically for all the roll numbers in mongoose. Like say we have roll numbers 1 to 10 i.e 10 records and we have to find average of  first_round and second_round and third_round seperately for all the 10 roll numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want average of all the records combined then try [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/),

- `$group` by null and average all fields using [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/index.html)

```
let result = await ModelName.aggregate([
  // match condition to match for specific rollno
  // { $match: { rollno: { $in: [1,2] } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total_average: { $avg: "$total" },
      first_round: { $avg: "$first_round" },
      second_round: { $avg: "$second_round" },
      third_round: { $avg: "$third_round" }
    }
  }
], { allowDiskUse: true });
console.log(result);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B6DDMncxEun)

Comment: I want to find average of each rounds separately. Not just for a specific roll no but for all the records, basically for all the roll numbers in mongoose.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Last question. How can I display the output for this in console.log?

Comment: By doing that I just get a huge Object back, SOmething that looks like: AggregationCursor {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 16,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },

Comment: updated answer with property `allowDiskUse: true` try that, but i am not sure exactly you are missing something or doing wrong.

Comment: Here is my code for this: https://imgur.com/a/TWIaXhU , What have I done wrong?

Comment: write `async` in callback connect function.

Comment: Verify the connection perfectly [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#the-single-server-connection), and try removing async and await, i am not sure looks good, might be you missed something.

Comment: All seems fine. I have no idea why it keeps on outputting this object.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this using `mongoDB aggregation`. And in `aggregation` you can use `$group` to evaluate your avgs of each rounds for all records.

```
db.sales.aggregate(
 [
  { 
   $group:
     {
       _id: "$item",
       first_round_av: { $avg: "$first_round" },
       second_round_av: { $avg: "$second_round" },
       third_round_av: { $avg: "$third_round" },
     }
   }
  ]
 )
```

Comment: I want to find average of each rounds separately. Not just for a specific roll no but for all the records, basically for all the roll numbers in mongoose. Like say we have roll numbers 1 to 10 i.e 10 records and we have to find average of  first_round and second_round and third_round seperately for all the 10 roll numbers.

Comment: @pranshuverma i have updated my answer. This is the most simplest way to get avg of all rounds separately for all records.